# How do I write an If statement to check for the existence of text in a VB textbox?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I want a statement that will check for text in a label/textbox. For example:

```
If TextBox1.Text = True then Label1.Show
```

OR

```
If Label1.Text = False then Label1.Visible = False
```

I want my label to hide itself when there's no text input into it. I have it to where my next from `TextBox1` is input as the text of `Label1`, but I want `Label1` to hide when there is no text put in the textbox.

I've tried multiple methods but none seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This checks for empty, null, or whitespace-only, so there is no need to Trim().  If you don't like it on one line, you can put it inside an If statement.

```
Label1.Visible = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Label1.Text)
```

Comment: Exactly what I would have written.

Answer (score 2):

If you simple need to check for whether textbox/label has value, the construct is

```
if label1.text.Trim() = ""
```

or

```
if label1.text.Trim() = String.Empty
```

*Update* To show/hide control based on existance of the text you can use oneliner:

```
Label1.Visible = (Label1.Text.Trim() <> "")
```

Comment: Do not forget to add a Trim for the textbox check

Comment: Another approach is to use String.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: @PlantationGator True, but I doubt Text property of the control will ever have a Null value

Comment: True, it will never be null but it can be empty. It's really just equivalent to seeing if it equals ""